# Online classes/books in multivariable calculus?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, education, online-resources

So does anyone know of any good online courses in multivariable calculus? (Or in a possible alternative leap of curriculum, if said path has proven to be better/moar interesting.) I'm coming straight from BC Calc (5); but my high school doesn't offer math past that.

As for descriptions of the course...not being free is tolerable. The only real requirement-requirement would be that the class does not require presence in an online classroom. Also something that is important for me is I need some way of getting credit for the course--not necessarily high school type credits, but more of just a general report-card type thing which ensures to my high school that I'm learning math. (So MIT OCW would be difficult in this aspect...)

As for books, I have the book *Calculus, a New Horizon* (ISBN 0471482730)), which is just a normal textbook that tided me over through single variable calc and supposedly should last through multivariable calculus as well. However if you know of books that are significantly better, please name them!

Comment: [Paul's online notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/CalcIII.aspx) are excellent.

Comment: I second David's suggestion. I often look through Paul's notes and Stewart's multivariate calculus textbook. The latter isn't too rigorous but nice. I also reference Lang's multivariate calculus as well, though it isn't something one should use upon first exposure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An excellent course is the online course by MIT: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02sc-multivariable-calculus-fall-2010/

An the best book I've read on the subject is the second calculus book written by Apostol, it explains the concepts in a very pure way, to a certain degree it is similar to Landau's approach on his physics books.