# Book on calculus of several variables.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, reference-request, soft-question, online-resources, book-recommendation

I'm an undergraduate student in mathematics and want to study Calculus of several variables currently this semester which involves the use of analysis, vector spaces and linear transformations.
Can anyone suggest me some good content I must refer to begin ,available online or a book?

Comment: All three books mentioned in the answer here are useful http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/909163/which-book-is-appropriate-for-a-chemistry-student-that-needs-to-learn-basics-abo/909238#909238

Comment: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/

Comment: I really like Serge Lang's *Calculus of Several Variables*. I find his explanations to be crystal-clear and, unlike most calculus books, the text is not overly burdened with distracting graphics or drill exercises.

Comment: @Bungo: I too like Lang's *Calculus of Several Variables* (see [here](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=7365390)), and there has been at least one math StackExchange question about Lang's calculus books -- [Would it be fine to use Serge Lang's two Calculus books as textbooks for freshman as Maths major?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31733/would-it-be-fine-to-use-serge-langs-two-calculus-books-as-textbooks-for-freshma).

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472726/online-classes-books-in-multivariable-calculus and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/918913/suggested-textbook-for-multivariable-calculus
You might find a few more similar questions by looking at questions tagged [multivariable-calculus+reference-request](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multivariable-calculus+reference-request).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you must have already taken a basic course into calculus and analysis, so the book **Analysis In Vector Spaces-A course in advanced Calculus** can be a good place for you to start with. The chapters $3$ to $5$ which I have read were very well-explained ...

Comment: Do you mean the book **Analysis In Vector Spaces-A course in advanced Calculus** by Mustafa A.Akcoglu ,Bartha,Dzung M.Ha.Our profesor also suggested it but I never paid attention...

Comment: @spectraa yes exactly...

Answer (score 4):

Chapters 1-6 of the book "Functions of Several Real Variables" by Moskowitz and Paliogiannis discusses all these in detail and with many illustrative examples.