# Suggested textbook for Multivariable Calculus

Tags: multivariable-calculus, reference-request, book-recommendation

I have just finished single variable differential/integral calculus (with a little bit of infinite series).

I'd like to jump right into the multivariable stuff; given that I intend to major in engineering (definitely not pure mathematics). Which textbook would you recommend that covers integral/differential calculus of several variables?

I am more interested in the computational stuff than the "proofs" if that makes sense.

Some I've heard of are

Stewart /
Spivak - Calculus on manifolds/
Anton/
Howard/
Edwards

Thank you very much!

Comment: If you're not interested in pure mathematics, *do not* try to read *Calculus on Manifolds.*

Answer (score 1):

I don't Spivak is the sort of thing you'll want.  You might consider Apostol's *Calculus*. Volume 2 is multi-variable and contains many topics relevant for the physical sciences -- Caltech background.  The text is an older one, and you can find low cost sources using Google.  The material is challenging, but there solutions included to some problems, so that's nice.  Also you should check the Schaum outlines.  They may be well-suited to your needs.  Enjoy.  The subject is significantly more complicated to grasp than the single-variable materials, but definitely important for applications.

Answer (score 0):

I used *Vector Calculus* by Marsden and Tromba, thought it was good.

Comment: Thank you I will definitely take that into consideration!

Comment: You'll probably find that people frequently tend to recommend the texts they used.

Answer (score 0):

I used [Calculus, Single and Multivariable (3rd edition) by Hughes-Hallet, Gleason, McCallum, et al.](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1156193.Calculus_Single_and_Multivariable) in high school and I liked it. In college I used [Multivariable Calculus with Vectors by Hartley Rogers](http://smile.amazon.com/Multivariable-Calculus-Vectors-Hartley-Rogers/dp/0136056431/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1409804199&sr=8-1&keywords=multivariable+calculus+with+vectors+rogers). The former is easier to understand and the latter is more rigorous.